# Image Cropping Control for WinForms with Selection Rectangle

Tags: .net, picturebox, system.drawing, crop

I need a control that allows user to select a rectangular area of the image and apply simple "Crop to selection" feature. Found several options but none of them is consistent with large images - the control must be able to show the entire image (like the zoom mode in PictureBox). All controls I've found use PictureBox Normal SizeMode, which limits the crop selection area when the PictureBox exceeds container bounds.

Comment: Well, use Zoom.  You only have to map the rectangle to pixels.